# Clearing the Protection history (not the same as Detection history)

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

There is a Windows Defender feature that - separate from the malware *detection* history - notes restrictions for programs not already known to be intentionally dangerous, like Protected Folder Access (programs not granted access to user folders) or Protected Memory Access (programs attempting to access data they never should).

I believe it is - contrary to replies to [related forum posts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/answer-is-not-in-that-other-castle/592e35f3-6d5c-4052-92d5-faf2a216262f) - a separate log because I have followed the instructions to clear the detection log, and the entries in the protection log remain (after 2 reboots and 2 days). The `Get-MpThreat` command now produces no output while the protection log still contains entries.

That log exceeding an unknown limit makes relevant Windows settings dialogues crash, and may also be responsible for crashing applications affected by the feature. I have resolved the problem before by reinstalling Windows 10 and it reoccurred.

The *detection log* is stored at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Scans\History\Service\DetectionHistory` and can be expired by calling `Set-MpPreference -ScanPurgeItemsAfterDelay 1`

Where is the *protection log* stored - or what other options are provided to clear that history?

Comment: Why are you linking Microsoft Answers, answers which I might add, are don't answer your question.  Even if they did answer your question, an answer here would have to be submitted, that perhaps referenced the solutions.  I would argue those are some of the worst answers I have seen anywhere, they are unhelpful, and don't answer your question.

Comment: Why do you believe two separate logs are kept? The only other log I am aware that exists for Windows Defender is `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Scans\History`

Comment: Can you confirm `Get-MpThreat` displays the threats you want to clear?

Answer (score 0):

The protection history is stored in a database file adjacent to the `DetectionHistory` folder. I am not aware of any documented way of maintaining that database. However, it will be recreated empty when deleted while defender was not running:

1. shift-click on "Reboot" to bring up advanced startup options
2. select "command line"
3. wait for that startup option to load, use it to execute this command

   ```
   del "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Scans\mpenginedb.db
   ```
4. quit the command line and continue to normal boot
5. confirm by opening the protection history, which should now only contain entries generated since the first boot after deleting but remain functional otherwise

Caveat: I am unable to tell if this deletes any information on top of those protection history entries.